# Best way to insert an array of jQuery elements to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best way of appending an array of jQuery elements to the page?

I know that if I'm appending straight HTML tags then they should be collected together in an array then the array appended. This is the fastest method. However I have a collection of jQuery elements that have events created on them so I can't just concatenate strings together.

Example:

```
        function displayCommentActions(actions) {
            var html = [];
            module.$element.find('.comments .actions li').remove();
            $.each(actions, function(key, value) {
                html.push($('<li class="' + key + '"><a href="#">' + value.name + '</a></li>').bind({
                    click: function(event) {
                        alert('found click');
                    }
                }));
            });
            $.each(html, function(count, item) {
                module.$element.find('.comments .actions').append(item);
            })
        };
```

This is ugly because it takes two loops. One to create the jQuery objects and one to output them to the page. How can I improve my code?

Comment: "...so I can just concatenate strings..." - Did you mean "I **can't** just concatenate strings?"

Comment: why do the DOM elements need to be stored in an array before appending them to the page?

Comment: @George Yep, I've fixed the spelling mistake. @GerMansson They don't however I'm in the habit of creating an array of strings before joining them inside an append call when writing to the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@efritz, doing .remove() on every list item is slow and expensive, a quick wipe of list items would be .empty().

@Samuel you can't avoid looping here. .append() takes either a string (of html) or a jquery object. It can't take an array of jquery objects.

```
var actionsList = module.$element.find('.comments .actions');
actionsList.empty() // Remove all contents of our <UL>
$.each(actions, function(class, value) {
    var listItem = $('<li />').addClass(class) // Create our <li> and add our class
        .append('<a href="javascript:void(0);">' + value.name + '</a>') // Add our link
        .click(function() { // Click bind event
            alert('Clicked item');
        });

     actionsList.append(listItem); // Add our <li> to our <ul>

 }
```

This is probably as small as you're gonna get it Samuel, it's an improvement from your dual-loop at least.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this not work?

```
function displayCommentActions(actions) {
    var target = module.$element.find('.comments .actions li')
    target.remove();

    $.each(actions, function(k, v) {
        var item = $('<li />').addClass(key);

        var link = $('<a />')
            .attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);')
            .html(value.name)
            .click(function() {
                alert('found click');
            });

        elem.append(item);
        target.append(item);
    }
}
```

Also, remember that repeated selectors can be expensive - store them if at all possible.

Comment: That solves the problem with the two loops, I'm still appending elements one at a time however.